# Weird button behavior while scrapping bet365

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, pyppeteer

I am trying to scrap odd data by Pyppeteer from bet365 follow their UI flow and need for help.
The pages are just like this.

https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B1/C1/D8/E123540970/F3/

If the match is outdated, just get into one of the matches that not in-played from following.

https://www.bet365.com/#/AS/B1/

For the collapsed button named "Handicap Result" at the bottom of the page, I can normally use my mouse cursor to click on it and make it expand and retrieve its data.

[image]

But when I tried to use Pyppeteer's click or javascript to do it, that is `querySelector()` and `click()`, it just weirdly failed.

Observing html and xhr after `click()`, it definitely triggered something and tried to do something, but the content just failed to shown.

I tried to click on different coordinates, key Enter and Space, click with delay, and all failed.

Could someone tell me how could I expand it use javascript?

Was I dissipating wrong events?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably one way they use to avoid scraping.

U tested with pure JS direct from DevTools?

Bet365 its really, really hard to scrape. They use Cloudflare blocking and protection system (including AI to detect autonomous agent like Puppeteer, even if you use stealth mode).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33045606)